# Change grafana.ini in IstioControlPlane using istioctl

Tags: grafana, istio, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, istio-kiali

I am running grafana (kiali, prometheus and tracing too) inside an Azure Kubernetes Cluster (AKS). The AKS cluster is behind an Application Gateway Ingress Controller (AGIC) the grafana pod is running in a subpath like https://{domain}/grafana/. I am able to hit the grafana service through an ingress of AGIC bit the grafana pod keeps searching for resources in https://{domain}/ and not in https://{domain}/grafana/.
So, I would like to change the propertie root_url in grafana.ini in order to solve the problem. How could I achieve this?

I am installing istio 1.6 in AKS with the command:

```
istioctl manifest apply -f istio.aks.yaml
```

My IstioControlPlane looks like below:

```html
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: IstioControlPlane
spec:
  # Use the default profile as the base
  # More details at: https://istio.io/docs/setup/additional-setup/config-profiles/
  profile: default
  components:
    pilot:
      k8s:
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m # override from default 500m
            memory: 40Mi # ... default 2048Mi
  values:
    global:
      # Ensure that the Istio pods are only scheduled to run on Linux nodes
      defaultNodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
      # Enable mutual TLS for the control plane
      controlPlaneSecurityEnabled: true
      mtls:
        # Require all service to service communication to have mtls
        enabled: false
    grafana:
      # Enable Grafana deployment for analytics and monitoring dashboards
      enabled: true
      security:
        # Enable authentication for Grafana
        enabled: false
    kiali:
      # Enable the Kiali deployment for a service mesh observability dashboard
      enabled: true
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 2m # override from default 500m
    tracing:
      # Enable the Jaeger deployment for tracing
      enabled: true
      jaeger:
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 2m # override from default 500m
    gateways:
      istio-ingressgateway:
        enabled: false
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 2m # override from default 500m
```

The grafana web page at https://{domain}.com/grafana/ returns the error in the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Nx1z.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are deploying Grafana using the ItsioControlPlane CRD, you should be able to update the manifest by updating the following ENV variable.

```
    grafana:
      env:
        GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL: '%(protocol)s://%(domain)s:/grafana'
```

this will allow you to change its ROOT URL and have it properly served behind an Azure AppGW

This is available since all of the itsio HelmChart configurations are mapped in the CRD

https://istio.io/latest/blog/2019/introducing-istio-operator/#migration-from-helm

> You can also set Helm configuration values in an IstioControlPlane custom resource. See Customize Istio settings using Helm for details.